# Time only: cast to (or extract from) a timestamp its time part, or cast a long to a time (but not to a datetime or a timestamp), with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, time, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

From a `Dataset`, I'm executing this request:

```sql
select type, count(*) as nombre, max(date) as derniere_course, 
   round(avg(distance), 1) as distance, 
   avg(allure_moyenne) as allure_moyenne,
   cast(avg(allure_moyenne) as timestamp) as allure,
   round(avg(foulees_moy), 2) as foulees 
   from activites
   group by type
   order by type
```

where fields have this type (`printSchema()`):

```
 |-- date: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- allure_moyenne: double (nullable = true)
 |-- distance: double (nullable = true)
 |-- foulees_moy: double (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = false)
```

---

That request shows me:

```
"type","nombre","derniere_course","distance","allure_moyenne","allure","foulees"
"Court",160,2023-09-06 05:29:05.0,3.6,452.09375,1970-01-01 01:07:32.09375,0.86
"Long",11,2023-08-09 10:00:50.0,17.0,469.45454545454544,1970-01-01 01:07:49.454545,0.83
"Moyen",46,2023-09-02 09:34:39.0,8.1,462.5869565217391,1970-01-01 01:07:42.586956,0.84
```

where `allure_moyenne` (452.1, 469.4...) is my running speed in seconds per kilometer, for shorts, medium or longs runs.

But there are two issues here, with the conversion from `allure_moyenne` to `allure`:

```
452.09375 => 1970-01-01 01:07:32.09375
469.45454545454544 => 1970-01-01 01:07:49
462.5869565217391 => 1970-01-01 01:07:42
```

- The time part of the timestamp looks correct for my time zone:

  - 452 seconds is `7:32`, but the timestamp displays: `01:07:32`
  - 469 seconds is `7:49` and becomes `01:07:49`
  - 462 is `7:42` => `01:07:42`
- And I'm only willing to see the time part of a timestamp (or you can call it a duration, if it's more exact).

But I've found nothing with *Spark* related to time, only.

`cast(avg(allure_moyenne) as time)` doesn't work,
and if `to_date(...)` or `to_timestamp(...)` exist, there's no `to_time(...)` function.

I've attempted `to_timestamp(cast(avg(allure_moyenne) as timestamp), 'hh:mm:ss')` which is  clumsy, but it didn't work either.

Even if it can only be achieved by extracting result as a `string`, rather than `time`, I would be interested in a solution that creates a field looking like `07:32` or `07:32.09375` at the end.

Comment: You seem to be casting a double as a timestamp?  `cast(avg(allure_moyenne) as timestamp)`.  That seems completely meaningless to me.

Comment: @Andrew The number I've received is a double, coming from a mean of values. Casting it as a timestamp makes timestamp consider it as seconds elapsed (from Unix date 1970/01/01), whatever. It uses the decimal part of these numbers to fill the value below the second of the timestamp. You can check that it is working. Casting `long` to date or time is a classical practice (millis or nanos are common). Then, why using a `double` would not work? My double value is expressed in seconds, and a second has subdivisions.

Comment: So allure_moyenne is seconds?  What is your desired output?

Comment: I would like to have to see 452.09375 transformed into `07:32.09375`, instead of `1970-01-01 01:07:32.09375` or `01:07:32.09375` I have here. I can do that dirtily by using concat and doing divisions and remainders by 3600, 60 to extract hours, minutes, seconds from 452.09, but I would like to see if a cast(time) can be done by any better way, such like cast(date) or cast(datetime) is possible.

Comment: @Andrew if I put over my sql request a very very dark `select format_string("%02d:%02d:%02d", hh, mm, ss) as time from (select allure_moyenne, floor(allure_moyenne/3600.0) as hh, floor((allure_moyenne%3600.0)/60.0) as mm, floor((allure_moyenne%3600.0)%60) as ss from ([...existing request....])))`, it will produce the `00:07:32` and others times I am looking for. But you see how it is... Not nice at all!

Comment: You could substring out the time portion of it  `select substring(cast(cast('452.09375' as double) as timestamp),15,11)`.  A little goofy, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Spark 3.+](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/sql-ref-functions-builtin.html#date-and-timestamp-functions) it can be as simple as

```
scala> spark.sql("select substring(timestamp_seconds(452.09375d),15) as t0").show(false)
+-----------+
|t0         |
+-----------+
|07:32.09375|
+-----------+

scala> spark.version
res1: String = 3.3.2
```

Comment: Perfect! Eventually, I've decided to round my decimal number to avoid the value below the second. `substring(timestamp_seconds(round(avg(allure_moyenne))),15) as allure` gave me `07:32`, `07:46`, the results I wished to see. Your reply is the trick I was looking for to avoid all that clumsy code I've wrote until now. It also avoid the translation of one hour that my time zone caused with the simple use of a cast to `timestamp`. Thanks again!